# Radio button issues with multiple-choice quiz

Tags: html, angular, typescript, radio-button

I'm making a website where you can make quizzes and answer them. My issue is that when I try to answer my quiz, to see whether the answer is correct or incorrect, the result I get is not exactly what I want.

I'm creating my html page by loading a json and assigning a radio button to every answer. The structure is that a quiz can have many questions, and questions can have many answers.

HTML:

```
<table class="pageTable" align="center">
<!-- Quiz title -->
<div *ngFor="let quiz of quizToDisplay"><br/>
    Quiz title: {{quiz.title}} <br/> by {{quiz.owner}}<br/><br/>
    
    <!-- Quiz questions -->
    <div *ngFor="let quizQuestions of quiz.questions" align="center">
        <div class="Question-panel-title" style="padding: 10px; word-wrap: break-word;">
            Question: {{quizQuestions.questionText}}
        </div>

        <!-- Quiz answers -->
        <div class="Question-panel-content" style="padding: 5px; word-wrap: break-word;">
            <div *ngIf="quizQuestions.types == 'Multiple-choice'" >
                <div *ngFor="let quizAnswers of quizQuestions.answers; let i=index">
                    <input type="radio" id="rawr" name="{{quizQuestions.questionText}}" value="{{quizAnswers.correctAnswer}}" [disabled]="submitted">
                    {{i + 1}}: {{quizAnswers.answerText}}    
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="submitted == true">
                    Your answer is {{correctAnswerMultipleChoice}}
                </div>
            </div>
        
            <div *ngIf="quizQuestions.types == 'Checkboxes'">
                <div *ngFor="let quizAnswers of quizQuestions.answers; let i=index">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkboxGroup" value="{{quizAnswers.correctAnswer}}" [disabled]="submitted" (click)="handleCheckboxAnswer(i, quizAnswers.correctAnswer)">
                    {{i + 1}}: {{quizAnswers.answerText}}    
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="submitted == true">
                    Your answer is {{correctAnswerCheckbox}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><br/>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" (click)="submitAnswer()">
    <input type="submit" value="View Statistics">
    <div *ngIf="quiz.owner == currentUser">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete Quiz" (click)="deleteQuiz(quiz.id)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Code:

```
export class QuizComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
service: any;
data: any;
quizToDisplay: any;
currentUser: string;
correctAnswerMultipleChoice: string = 'Incorrect';
CheckboxesValues: string[] = [];
correctAnswerCheckbox: string = 'Incorrect';
submitted: boolean = false;
answersArray: any[] = [];

constructor(private router:Router, private quizObserverService:QuizObserverService, private socketService:SocketService, private elementRef:ElementRef){
    this.currentUser = localStorage.getItem('user');
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.service = this.quizObserverService.getQuiz(this.router.url).subscribe(data => { //only gets JSON upon page load
        this.quizToDisplay = data;
    })
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this.service.unsubscribe();
}

deleteQuiz(id: string){
    this.socketService.socket.emit('deleteQuiz', JSON.stringify(id));
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
}

handleMultiplechoiceAnswer(){
    let rawr = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('#rawr');

    

    for(let i = 0; i < this.quizToDisplay[0].questions.length; i++){
        if(this.quizToDisplay[0].questions[i].types == "Multiple-choice"){
            for(let j = 0; j < this.quizToDisplay[0].questions[i].answers.length; j++){
                this.answersArray.push(this.quizToDisplay[0].questions[i].answers[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    if(this.handleMultiplechoiceAnswerCorrect(rawr)){
        return this.handleMultiplechoiceAnswerCorrect(rawr);
    }
    else
    {
        return this.handleMultiplechoiceAnswerIncorrect(rawr);
    }
}

handleMultiplechoiceAnswerCorrect(rawr: any){
    for(let k = 0; k < rawr.length; k++){

        if(this.answersArray[k].correctAnswer == rawr[k].value && rawr[k].value == "Correct" && rawr[k].checked == true){ 
            return "Correct";
        }
    }
}

handleMultiplechoiceAnswerIncorrect(rawr: any){
    return "Incorrect";
}

handleCheckboxAnswer(index: number, correct: string) {
    this.CheckboxesValues[index] = correct;
}

submitAnswer(){
    this.submitted = true;
    this.correctAnswerMultipleChoice = this.handleMultiplechoiceAnswer();
}
```

When I try to answer my quiz, this is what the result looks like:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k1MWW.png)

As you can see, even though the second question is answered wrong, it still says that it is correct, because the first question is answered correctly. The method I'm using to determine whether the quiz is correct or false is the `handleMultiplechoiceAnswer()` method, so I think something is wrong in that method, however I can't pick my finger on it. Thanks for the help.

**EDIT:**
Very sorry, I forgot to put an example of my json structure. Here it is:

```html
{
  "id": "32bec4d6-b5fd-4360-bede-9c902abd95de",
  "title": "random quiz",
  "owner": "mohemohe",
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionText": "Choose numbers above 10",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answerText": "9",
          "correctAnswer": "Incorrect"
        },
        {
          "answerText": "11",
          "correctAnswer": "Correct"
        }
      ],
      "types": "Multiple-choice"
    },
    {
      "questionText": "Which website is this?",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answerText": "stackoverflow",
          "correctAnswer": "Correct"
        },
        {
          "answerText": "google",
          "correctAnswer": "Incorrect"
        }
      ],
      "types": "Multiple-choice"
    }
  ],
  "access": "Public"
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Managed to make a plunker example: https://plnkr.co/edit/CoV1AQtVtbbS2kNYK7FR

Comment: This is quite hard to work with as your code has no comments and there is no plunkr. Also, can you please provide an example of a questions json.

Answer (score 2):

**The solve:**

I think that the reason why this is always returning `true` / `'Correct'` is because of the `if` statement evaluating it:

```
if(this.answersArray[k].correctAnswer == rawr[k].value && rawr[k].value == "Correct" && rawr[k].checked == true){...}
```

If we break this down...

1. `this.answersArray[k].correctAnswer == rawr[k].value`
2. `rawr[k].value == "Correct"`
3. `rawr[k].checked == true`

Instantly you can see that you are expecting `rawr[k].value` to equal both `correctAnswer` **AND** `'Correct'`. Because the result is always returning true, this means that `this.answersArray[k].correctAnswer == 'Correct'`.

So this essentially negates the first 2 conditions in your if statement - so essentially your if statement becomes... `if(rawr[k].checked == true)`.

Just FYI there is absolutely no need for even checking `rawr[k].checked == true` if you swap `querySelectorAll('#rawr');` to `querySelectorAll('#rawr:checked');`

---

**The following is just general feedback:**

I think that you really need to consider re-working this entire script. It is very hard to read, highly un-optomised and needs to be refactored into a more robust approach.

First I would recommend creating a variable to store the `currentQuestion` so that you don't have to do `quizToDisplay[0]` every single time.

```
var currentQuestion: any;
ngOnInit(){
  ....
  this.quizToDisplay = data;
  this.currentQuestion = this.quizToDisplay[0];
}
```

Or at the very least... `this.quizToDisplay = data[0]`

---

Go and check out [`es6`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) array methods.

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.quizToDisplay[0].questions.length; i++){
        if(this.quizToDisplay[0].questions[i].types == "Multiple-choice"){
            for(let j = 0; j < this.quizToDisplay[0].questions[i].answers.length; j++){
                this.answersArray.push(this.quizToDisplay[0].questions[i].answers[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Can be transmutted into the following which is much easier to read:

```
this.quizToDisplay[0].questions.forEach((questionGroup, i)=>{
   if(questionGroup.types == "Multiple-choice"){
      questionGroup.forEach((question, ii)=>{
           this.answersArray.push(question.answers[ii]);
      });
   }
});
```

---

Why not just include the feedback string in the json for each question? That way you can do something like the following and mitigate any future requirements that the feedback string is unique for a particular question:

```
<div *ngIf="submitted == true">
    <p *ngIf="correct" class="correct-colour">{{quizAnswers.correctFeedback}}</p>
    <p *ngIf="!correct" class="incorrect-colour">{{quizAnswers.incorrectFeedback}}</p>
 </div>
```

---

I think that the naming conventions need to be improved. for example: `quizQuestions.answers` should be `quizQuestions.options`.

---

Don't forget that as you are using an object, you have the ability to assign new object properties *"on the fly"*. For example you could do:

```
this.quizToDisplay[0]['answeredCorrectly'] = true;
```

---

I would strongly recommend creating a click event on your `<input>` so that you can trap the selected options more effectively. Using the above methodology you could...

```
// .html
<input ... (click)="optionClicked(option)">

// .ts
optionClicked(_option: Object){
    quizQuestions['clicked'] = !quizQuestions['clicked'] || true;
}
```

---

If you ever want future code review, try [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! I tried to change the if statement that checks whether the selected value is the correct value to: if(rawr[k].checked == true){ 
       return "Correct";
}
however that still returns "Correct" to both questions, EVEN if I only decide to check an answer on question 1 and not question 2. Not sure why it's doing that. Example: http://imgur.com/a/oEvpC
Also, the reason why it says that it is correct that 9 is above 10 on the image is because i changed the if statement to return "Correct" even when it's only checked.

Comment: update, managed to make a plunker for you to check, sir :)
https://plnkr.co/edit/CoV1AQtVtbbS2kNYK7FR

Comment: @SquishyAura I'll have a look at this when I can. I would always expect `if(rawr[k].checked == true)` to be true. It's the other part of the if statement that is the issue... `this.answersArray[k].correctAnswer == rawr[k].value`
`rawr[k].value == "Correct"` <= what is the intended outcome for that? How can `rawr[k].value` equal 2 different things???

Comment: The reason behind that is that my json contains a correct/incorrect statement for each answer, so I wanted to check that if the selected answer is the same as the answer statement in the json, and the selected answer also is "Correct", then we know that the user answered the questions correctly.

Comment: @SquishyAura So I just checked out the plunkr. Put your original if statement back in - I think you missunderstood what I was saying about that. If you click the incorrect option first, then both say incorrect, then if you click correct option, they both become correct. This is because you are overwritting `correctAnswerMultipleChoice` and this is used commonly for both feedback options. To solve that you need to do something like: `<p *ngIf="quizAnswers.correct" class="correct-colour">{{quizAnswers.correctFeedback}}</p>`  and assign `quizAnswers.correct` after an option is submitted.

Answer (score 0):

```html
{
  "id": "32bec4d6-b5fd-4360-bede-9c902abd95de",
  "title": "random quiz",
  "owner": "mohemohe",
  "questions": [
    {
      "questionText": "Choose numbers above 10",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answerText": "9",
          "correctAnswer": "Incorrect"
        },
        {
          "answerText": "11",
          "correctAnswer": "Correct"
        }
      ],
      "types": "Multiple-choice"
    },
    {
      "questionText": "Which website is this?",
      "answers": [
        {
          "answerText": "stackoverflow",
          "correctAnswer": "Correct"
        },
        {
          "answerText": "google",
          "correctAnswer": "Incorrect"
        }
      ],
      "types": "Multiple-choice"
    }
  ],
  "access": "Public"
}
```